# MapR - How to Install Sqoop on a Client/Edge Node?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, mapr

I'm familiar with the Cloudera architecture but not MapR. I have a RHEL vm and previously installed the MapR client software using this [documentation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+Up+the+Client). I am able to submit mapreduce jobs and query HDFS as expected.

I followed this [documentation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Sqoop) (after I installed the MapR yum repo) and installed sqoop like so:

```
yum install mapr-sqoop
```

If I try to sqoop in some data, or even just issue the command `sqoop`, I receive the following error:

[image]

> /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.4/bin/configure-sqoop: line 47: /opt/mapr/bin/versions.sh: No such file or directory

```
Error: /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop- does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation.
```

I have a /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2 directory. I've tried setting `HADOOP_COMMON_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` to both `/opt/mapr/hadoop` and `/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2` yet still receive the same error.

-- Update:

I issued a `find / -name hadoop` and noted the last line which was `/usr/bin/hadoop`.

I then set HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to `/usr`, and was then asked to set HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME, HBASE_HOME, and HCAT_HOME, which I all set to `/usr`.

This error however is still present:

> /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.4/bin/configure-sqoop: line 47: /opt/mapr/bin/versions.sh: No such file or directory

I opened up this file and commented out line 47. This allowed me to use the sqoop command, but the import job failed and I received a lot of `Error: Unsupported major.minor version`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a patch for this if not fixed already,

Here is temp solution:

mapr-client does not give versions.sh , only mapr-core does. Simple fix is to
manually copy that file from a node with mapr-core installed and customize the
versions therein. sqoop then works fine.